# Is there a VBA function to enable the 'Start Time' of the Time sheet start from the next second of the 'End Time' of previous task?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to prepare a Time Sheet for my team. I need a function which will enable us to have the 'Start Time' of the Time sheet start from the next second of the 'End Time' of previous task. Example: Entry A - Start time - 04:30:00 and End Time - 05:00:00 then the function should be able to give the outcome as Entry B - Start time - 05:00:01 so on and so forth.

I'm unable to find any function for this as my VBA knowledge very limited. It'd be great if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with a simple formula.

Assuming that your Start Time is in Column A and the End Time in Column B, put the following formula in column A. As the first entry will probably be done manually (as there is no previous end time), start with the second row of data.

```
=IF(B2="","",B2+TIME(0,0,1))
```

[image]

(note that my Excel uses `;` as parameter separator)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looking for a VBA solution, Here is one. It requires your data be in a table, but can be modifies to work with regular ranges.

Three very similar subs to make the required changes.
You don't really need the "New" Button, but some users might prefer it.

```
Option Explicit
Sub NewStartTime()
    
    Dim TimeSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    
    Set TimeSheet = Sheet3
    With TimeSheet
        
        lRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If .Range("B" & lRow).Value = "" Then
            MsgBox "Period Already Active", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Error"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        .Range("A" & lRow + 1).Value = Format(Now(), "hh:mm:ss")
        
    End With
    
End Sub
Sub CycleTime()
    
    Dim TimeSheet As Worksheet
    Dim TM As Double
    Dim lRow As Long
    
    Set TimeSheet = Sheet3
    With TimeSheet
        
        lRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If .Range("B" & lRow).Value <> "" Then
            .Range("A" & lRow + 1).Value = Format(Now(), "hh:mm:ss")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        TM = Now()
        .Range("B" & lRow).Value = Format(TM, "hh:mm:ss")
        .Range("A" & lRow + 1).Value = Format(TM + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "hh:mm:ss")
        
    End With
    
End Sub
Sub EndTime()
    
    Dim TimeSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    
    Set TimeSheet = Sheet3
    With TimeSheet
    
        lRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If .Range("B" & lRow).Value <> "" Then
            MsgBox "No Time Started", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Error"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        .Range("B" & lRow).Value = Format(Now(), "hh:mm:ss")
        
    End With

End Sub
```

---

Results:

**Starting Table:**
[image]

**"New" Button**
[image]

**"Next Period" Button**
[image]

**"End" Button**
[image]

**"Next Period" button (when no period active)**
Acts like "New Button"
[image]

**"End" Button (when no period active)**
Error Message:
[image]

**"New" Button (when period already active)**
Error Message:
[image: Error Message:]